# Java main method

Tags: methods, program-entry-point

In a overloaded main method why the main method with signature String[] args is considered as the entry point.

e.g.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("why this is being printed");
    }

    public static void main(String arg1) {
        System.out.println("why is this not being printed");
    }

    public static void main(String arg1, String arg2) {
        System.out.println("why is this not being printed"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Because that's the just way Java works.

Answer (score 2):

The main method should have only 1 argument, of type `String[]` so the single string and 2 string forms are not valid main methods, and as such are not options, the only accepted forms are:

- `public static void main (String[])`
- `public static void main (String...)`

*The second option is syntactic sugar for the first option.*

This is set in the Java Language Specifications:

> **12.1. Java Virtual Machine Startup**
>
> The Java Virtual Machine starts execution by invoking the method main of some specified class, passing it a single argument, which is an array of strings...

[Link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.1)

Answer (score 0):

This is the way Java works and Java documentation describes that;

Signatures other than specified will simply not work as they do not comply with the standard.

> The java command starts a Java application. It does this by starting
>   the Java Runtime Environment (JRE), loading the specified class, and
>   calling that class's main() method. The method must be declared public
>   and static, it must not return any value, and it must accept a String
>   array as a parameter. The method declaration has the following form:
>
> public static void main(String[] args)

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html